# How do I supress/hide a row in jxls2?

Tags: jxls

I'm trying to hide (not generate) a row, if a condition is false. By now I'm always getting an empty row:

A1: Value: EMPTY

A1: Comment: jx:area(lastCell="B4")

A2: Value: SOME PRINT OUT

A2: Comment: jx:each(items="myList",var="myItem",lastCell="B3")

A3: Value: SOME CONDITIONAL PRINT OUT

A3: Comment:
jx:if(condition="myItem.hasSubItems == true", lastCell="B3", areas=["A3:B3"])
jx:each(items="myItem.subItems", var="subItem", lastCell="B3")

I don't want row3 to be generated, if myItem has no subItems

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually *jx:each* should not generate a row if the underlying collection is empty.

So in your case it should work even without *jx:if* tag.

But in a case when you need to apply some other condition your *jx:if* tag may look like this

```
jx:if(condition="YOUR CONDITION" lastCell="B3" areas=["A3:B3"])
```

Comment: I changed my template to A3 comment: `jx:each(items="myItem.subItems", var="subItem", lastCell="B3")` and I'm explicitly returning an empty collection (Collections.EMPTY_LIST) as I get an error when returning null. Still an empty row is generated.

Answer (score 0):

try this code to hide rows :

CellView cellView = new CellView();
    cellView.setHidden(true); //set hidden

```
sheet.setRowView(0, cellView);
sheet.setRowView(2, cellView);
sheet.setRowView(4, cellView);
```