# Conditionally remove/hide column using jxls2

Tags: java, excel, jxls

With `JXLS1.x`, I can conditionally hide columns using [this](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/1.x/reference/columnhiding.html).

What's corresponding API for that in `JXLS2.x`? Documentation only describes conditional if expressions on rows.

Comment: I dont have much idea about jxls. Check if the following can help or not:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995039/how-do-i-supress-hide-a-row-in-jxls2

Comment: Thanks, but that's about rows, and I need to exclude/hide a column

Comment: may be it could have .setColumnView() as .setRowView(), right? So maybe you can setColumnView as hidden or use the removeColumn method